# Is there any c# library/code which provide tab window form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I want a winform library that allow users to merge several window into tabs of a single window, and split a tab into new window, just like the Google Chrome and debug/compile output windows in Visual Studio. Is there any library or sample project that provides such feature? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Avalon Dock is a library that allows you to build Visual Studio like GUI's. Unfortunately this is not a win forms library (wpf) however you can use it with winform controls.

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is nice, but I am not familiar with wpf. Maybe I will learn it later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your "windows" as user controls and place every user control onto a seperate tab page on a tab control. It doesn't matter what controls the user control itself contains. So it can for sure also contain a tab control that itself hosts other user controls.

To use a window inside a user control you can host it inside a panel using the following WinAPI methods:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
public static extern bool ShowWindow( IntPtr hWnd, WindowShowStyle nCmdShow );

[DllImport( "user32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent( IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent );
```

Example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process externalProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process( )
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo( appToHost )
};
externalProcess.Start( );
externalProcess.WaitForInputIdle( );
if ( !externalProcess.HasExited )
{
    ShowWindow( externalProcess.MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowStyle.Maximize );
    SetParent( externalProcess.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle );
}
```

This snippet adds the application located at `appToHost` as a child control into the panel `panel`.

Answer (score 0):

Use tab control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx

but for this you need to convert your form to user control and assign user control in tabs

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). It will let you do what you describe, as well as dragging and docking behaviors if you want.